# Magento 2: The newly added column does not appear in the product export csv file

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, importexport

When we export Magento products, in the CSV there is one column **related_skus**. I have added one column with the same name, **accessories_skus**. But when I export to the staging server on the live server, "**accessories_skus**" does not come in a csv file.

I have faced the same issue on my local system as well, but after rebooting my local system, the new column "**accessories_skus**" came in a csv file. because when the system reboots, my consumer queue is reset, and on the live site, we can't reboot the server. So please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: You can use this free extension to export custom product attribute to product export csv file.
https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-export-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-2/

Comment: @RizwanKhan, "accessories_skus" is not product attribute it similar like we are selecting related product same is this so it's not product attribute, it like product link type.